# Python encryption using PKCS1_OAEP not able to decrypt in java

Tags: python, java, encryption

Below code is used at server side for encryption in python:

```py
with open(key_file, 'wb') as f:
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key=rsa, hashAlgo=SHA256, mgfunc=lambda x,y: pss.MGF1(x,y, SHA1))
    encrypted_secret_key = cipher.encrypt(secret_key)
```

And, the java code used for decryption is as per below:

```java
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSpecified.DEFAULT);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, readPrivateKey(),oaepParams);
System.out.println(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(sValue))));
```

Eventhough, I am able to decrypt the string, but the decrypted string does not match with the original string.

Eg. Original string: `deUI1kjyzRH/EHBhg3c13A==`

After encryption using python: `dIQCt/QvgOSMPC3He0CxFyj5beAO5HCiZGX5IwEZu7Z4ZLf6afjF0AJGYTst5I4p8lo4tpYRljinoUm2LRq1ZxHPJ2q506Ro154qBtqetvW0AwSjNbqCz1QTPQe7fp17KKnlulo/HgR6zeeZdIMpjBz+KUV7LHrTWu1HWcl2wMX8HMDvgZPD2N/OCwMdFaI4KUTUdLs6viWjCbSheeBhXOqci7hPAe1lRLlTPet8Q7Wm1OtO+AisVpBTK/jmDrPKRIu1vr0F/uhQmEmF6kweIwh6Xqt9+q07gwVtBCHys2z84uowLs2bftbEoThpHZui2qPuS1bDwdWx9jTwVwpz5g==`

String after decryption using Java: `de+/vQjvv71I77+977+9Ee+/vRBwYe+/vXc177+9`

Please help.

Comment: It looks like the plaintext is UTF-8 decoded/encoded somewhere. Since the plaintext consists of non-UTF8 compliant byte sequences, the data is corrupted in the process. This way exactly the decrypted ciphertext can be reproduced, see online at jdoodle: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/kqN

Comment: Thank you so much @Topaco for your help. It helped coming to the exact cause of the reason.   Using only ANSI characters helped resolving the issue.